# Bluetooth only available after restart on Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: kubuntu, bluetooth

My Toshiba laptop running Kubuntu 18.04 doesn't recognize the Bluetooth adapter after a fresh start up. After restart it works. Symptoms are like this :

> ```
> $ sudo rfkill list
>
> 0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
>         Soft blocked: no
>         Hard blocked: no
> 1: phy0: Wireless LAN
>         Soft blocked: no
>         Hard blocked: no
> 2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
>         Soft blocked: no
>         Hard blocked: no
> 3: hci0: Bluetooth
>         Soft blocked: no
>         Hard blocked: no
> ```

yet the Bluetooth widget says : "no Bluetooth adapters found"
[image]

I found two solutions :

1. restart the machine
2. execute the below script

> ```
> sudo rfkill block bluetooth
> sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
> ```

What might cause this and what is the best way to make it work after a fresh start up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried various things like go into BIOS, turn off WiFi and Bluetooth, restart, turn them on and boot into the system; reload Bluetooth services; edit some configuration files, etc.
But what helps in my case is to tell the kernel to reload the `btusb` module.:

```
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```